# Converting Future-based API into Stream-based API

Tags: scala

At the moment a Future-based API is converted into Stream-based like this

```
def getUpdates(offset: Option[Int] = None): Future[Update] = ???

def updateStream(offset: Option[Int] = None): Stream[Update] = {
  val head = Await.result { getUpdates(offset) }

  head #:: updateStream(Some(head.update_id))
}
```

I'm not sure if using `Await` is a proper thing to do here. Is there a better way?

Comment: Depends on your use case. Every time you try to access an element from `updateStream` it will block until the element is processed. If that is what you want, I think this is the best way to do it.

Comment: @Alec  What I probably want to do is kinda "merge" say a thousand of these streams.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge"? Concatenate...? Interleave (based on which future finishes first)?